# Is there a way to query and filter the Google People API connections through contact group id?

Tags: node.js, api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-people-api

I'm using the Google People API to populate the address book of my dashboard. I have a lot of contacts so the idea is to filter contacts by creating a specific group for this service. What I need is basically the possibility to query all the connections filtered on a specific group id. It seems the official API has only "list" method without the chance to query on. I'm using the client libraries for node.js and here it is my code:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const getGoogleConnections = async (userToken) => {
  const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2;
  oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    'access_token': userToken, //Passport session user
  });

  const googlePeople = await google.people({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: oauth2Client,
  });

  const params = {
    resourceName: 'people/me',
    pageSize: 200,
    sortOrder: 'LAST_MODIFIED_DESCENDING',
    personFields: ['names', 'emailAddresses', 'memberships', 'organizations'],
  };

  const connections = await googlePeople.people.connections.list(params);
  return connections;
};
```

My response:

```
"connections": [
            {
                ... //returning all specified personFieldsValues 
                "memberships": [
                    {
                        "metadata": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "CONTACT",
                                "id": "id value"
                            }
                        },
                        "contactGroupMembership": {
                            "contactGroupId": "contact group id",
                            "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/contact group id"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "metadata": {
                            "source": {
                                "type": "CONTACT",
                                "id": "metadata id "
                            }
                        },
                        "contactGroupMembership": {
                            "contactGroupId": "myContacts",
                            "contactGroupResourceName": "contactGroups/myContacts"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
```

My response is correct and the API returns all the values but I can't find a way to filter these returned values on contact group id. Anyone tried this before?

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are no methods for directly filtering the returned values with "group id" for "people.connections" in People API. So as the current workaround, how about filtering the values by a script after the values were retrieved. But I'm not sure whether this is the same direction you expect. So I proposed this as a comment.

Comment: It takes time to load multiple resources from the endpoint so it could be an idea but I'll wait till they put a method to filter

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how about posting it as an answer of the current workaround? By this, I thought that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

#### Issue:

As was mentioned in comments [by Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64611021/is-there-a-way-to-query-and-filter-the-google-people-api-connections-through-con#comment114253922_64611021), there is no way to filter the returned connections when calling [people.connections.list](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list) (there's no optional query parameter or similar, unlike other `list` methods from Google APIs).

#### File a feature request:

I'd suggest you to request this on Issue Tracker's [People component](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/344199/manage#basic), if you think this functionality could be useful.

#### Workaround:

Meanwhile, what you can do is filtering the connections after they have been returned by the API. You could filter them according to the group ID the following way, using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const connections = await googlePeople.people.connections.list(params); 
const filteredConnections = connections.connections.filter(connection => {
  return connection.memberships.some(membership => {
    if (membership.contactGroupMembership) {
      return membership.contactGroupMembership.contactGroupId === "YOUR_GROUP_ID";
    } else return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Filter using C# code , not expressions like Gmail ?

Comment: @Kiquenet I'm unsure what you mean with `not expressions like Gmail`. Maybe you could consider posting a new question?

Comment: Search operators you can use with Gmail: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Comment: @Kiquenet What does this have to do with the current question and with People API?

Comment: Is this feature given now?

Comment: @Ranjani This is not possible yet. Consider filing a feature request.